# The underlying provider failed on Open C# Application

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I created a C# application with setup, but when install this in other computer i can't open database to read, the application give me this menssage -> "the underlying provider failed on open".

I tried a lot of things but don't result.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a connection String error, you have probably released the application with reference to the database on localhost. Try changing the connection string and then release again.